# Sharing (local) files in program instalation

Tags: java, file, url, local-files

I am somewhat new to programming and I'm building this small game of words. It uses local saved files, like this (*correct urls to be defined yet*):

```
    //declaring the URL class
    URL vEasyUrl = new File("C:\\Users\\lukas\\Desktop\\hardWords.html").toURI().toURL();
    URL easyUrl = new File("C:\\Users\\lukas\\Desktop\\hardWords.html").toURI().toURL();
    URL medUrl = new File("C:\\Users\\lukas\\Desktop\\hardWords.html").toURI().toURL();
    URL hardUrl = new File("C:\\Users\\lukas\\Desktop\\hardWords.html").toURI().toURL();
    URL vHardUrl = new File("C:\\Users\\lukas\\Desktop\\hardWords.html").toURI().toURL();
    URL crazyUrl = new File("C:\\Users\\lukas\\Desktop\\hardWords.html").toURI().toURL();
```

I'm afraid that when I share the game application it doesn't share the files as well, since it is saved on my machine. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Are you planning to make a jar or exe file?  If so, you can save the files into the jar, and access them by using `ClassName.class.getResource(String name)` - if you place the file into your root classpath folder (the one that contains .class files), then `name` can be `/hardWords.html` (the forward slash at the start means it'll look for the file from the root classpath folder).  Also, the `name` parameter accepts the file separator to be `/` regardless of OS.

Comment: @thorin9000 I think I'll be using launch4j to make an exe file, your answer was pretty clarifying, thanks